# Android 13 External Storage

Tags: android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-api-levels, android-13

Want to store user edited image bitmap to external storage inside app named folder and want to retrieve images from them in Android 13.

Please note am using Java code for my work.

I am able to work till api 30 but above that app crashes.